# c# Constraint: void Do(Action<T> action) where action : static?

Tags: c#, static, constraints

So I want to Serialize a list of `Action<T>` (or otherwise strongly-typed delegates or Tasks). I've found several links that provide some insight to serializing Anonymous Delegates and using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize an `Action<T>`, but I found that this only works if the `Action<T>`'s are marked static, or if their Declaring Type's are marked Serializable, and I serialize those declaring objects instead. I don't need object state for anything, just the reference to a static method, so...

How do I constrain `Action<T>` to only `where Action<T> : static`?

Comment: At runtime, you could examine `delegate.Target`; if it's null, the delegate has no bound argument.  It's also possible to create a custom serialization system for delegates with targets using `Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, firstArgument, method)` to recreate them, but I'd recommend against any delegate serialization as it will result in brittle code.

Comment: That kind of constraint doesn't exist as already pointed out. A runtime check could be done use the delgate's Method.IsStatic property. However even a runtime only check has some limitations. In C# 6 the compiler will generate a nonserializable closure class with an instance method for lambdas and anonymous methods that do not have any closed over variables. This will cause a runtime check to fail for common use cases.